# Does Wave have data mining features?

Tags: analytics-cloud

So my friend showed me around his access to analytics cloud.

Looked very fancy, works very fast - great product to do basic analytics like sum up or average records, group them up.

What I missed is more advanced data mining features used to build prediction models and so on.

Is that part of black belt training?

Or is it unreleased yet?

Perhaps Salesforce will never implement that as they are not targeting data scientists with Wave?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, wave doesn't have any data mining features. Basically the functionality is the ability to do data discovery across single or multiple datasets.

There are some Salesforce prediction partners, however I think most of them essentially require the import and export of the required data, they perform a standardised algorithm of which you can then import into Analytics Cloud . There is no Predictive Analytics on platform.

With middleware you can import datasets onto analytics cloud that can be architected around Predictive and outputs from data mining. ( i.e. the automation of finding trends / patterns)

Black belt Training - Is essentially: Completion of the Analytics Cloud Brown belt, completing a full implementation, and have  a case study with feedback from Client.

Salesforce Analytics is a productivity tool, this is a tool to support the greater data democracy by putting actionable data in the hands of lots of people in an organisation. Data Scientist --> Data Citizen . Essentially looking for actionable insight by the end user.

Im sure as the platform goes there will be partners, and features released that support predictive.